# Ordering values from random list in Excel

Tags: excel

is there any possibility how to order values from cca 100 rows into table according to two criteria? Compare name and compare Category, or is it bad approach?

Lets say i have a list of people:

```
   Name     Category   Value
    Carl         A          10
    Carl         B          17
    John         A          11
    Jane         A           7
    John         B          22
```

Name of person can be in row no. 3 or no. 30 or no.10. but there are 3 Categories A,B,C
How can i order them to  table according to categories?

```
Name    A   B   C
Carl    10  17  
John    11  22  
Jane    7
```

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with:

[image]

Running this small macro:

```
Sub TwoDee()
    Dim s1 As Worksheet, s2 As Worksheet
    Dim N As Long, i As Long, v1 As String, v2 As String, v3 As Long
    Dim iRow As Long, iCol As Long
    Set s1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set s2 = Sheets("Sheet2")
    s2.Cells.Clear

    N = s1.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    s1.Range("A1:B" & N).Copy s2.Range("A2")
    s2.Range("A:A").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
    s2.Range("B:B").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
    s2.Range("B2:B" & N).Copy
    s2.Range("B1").PasteSpecial Transpose:=True
    s2.Range("B2:B" & N).Clear

    For i = 1 To N
        v1 = s1.Cells(i, 1).Value
        v2 = s1.Cells(i, 2).Value
        v3 = s1.Cells(i, 3).Value
        iRow = s2.Range("A:A").Find(What:=v1, After:=s2.Range("A1")).Row
        iCol = s2.Range("1:1").Find(What:=v2, After:=s2.Range("A1")).Column
        s2.Cells(iRow, iCol) = v3
    Next i
End Sub
```

Will produce:

[image]

In the second worksheet.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something really close yo what you want using a pivot table:

[image]

The layout isn't quite the same as in your question, but it does order them by category.

To insert the pivot table, just go to Insert -> Pivot Table, select the range your table is in and then drag the various headers from the top of the pivot table helper pane to the fields you see them in, in the bottom right corner of the image above.